# Display only the first n field items

Tags: entities

Goal: For a multiple-value field, display only the first n (e.g. the first 3) field items.

E.g. only the first 3 of 10 images in an image field.

I realize this is possibly by writing a custom field formatter. But I wonder if there is an existing solution available. Also to mix this up with existing formatters.

Hint: I use Display Suite, so solutions which involve that are welcome.

Comment: I dont have time to go into an answer but I can give a quick suggestion.  You can create a view filter by content id in the url and display the first 3 images using views.  Then create a display suite dynamic field and you can pull in that view block as if it was a field.

Comment: True.
It always appears overkill to use Views for this, but it might indeed be the best solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a setting how many items to display in Display Suite. The setting is demoed in this screencast: http://youtu.be/fa56OZcJq-4?t=1m20s

Comment: Wow, this is awesome! How did I miss it?

Answer (score 2):

Specifically for images there's the [Image Delta Formatter](https://drupal.org/project/image_delta_formatter) module

> This module provides a custom formatter for imagefields, that allows the user to specify which values (deltas) should be displayed.

Comment: I am going with the solution mentioned by Pontus Nilsson. But maybe this will be useful for me or other visitors in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Manage Display to display fields, you can try out [Field multiple limit](https://drupal.org/project/field_multiple_limit)

[UI example](https://drupal.org/files/project-images/field_multiple_limit_settings.png)

> This is a simple module that provides settings to limit the number of
>   values to display on fields with multiple values.
>
> The module extends the field display settings for fields which permit
>   multiple values. Site administrators can specify how many values to
>   display for each display mode (e.g. teaser). Optionally, an off-set
>   can be specified to skip some values.

Comment: I am going with the solution mentioned by Pontus Nilsson. But this is a legit and useful answer nevertheless. Thanks!